# Replace PHP mail function with customised version

Tags: php, sendmail

I am currently working on an Email Server program that will keep track of emails that are sent via my website/web apps, and retry any that may fail due to SMTP errors.

What I am looking at being able to do is to replace the default method that PHP uses to send email.

I've tried creating a php script that has the same parameters as the mail function and adding this script to the sendmail path in the php.ini file but when I try this the browser just sits their not doing anything.

The idea is that the user would only need to reconfigure php to use my own version instead of having to write different code, i.e. they can the exactly the same code that they currently use to send email via php but instead of php doing the send, it just passes the details required to my own version to pass it on to the email server.

Is this something that this possible, thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `runkit` extension installed, you may be interested in using `runkit_function_redefine` to override the `email` function. Unfortunately, with PHP, native overriding of functions is not supported.

**Reference**: http://ca.php.net/runkit

**Reference**: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php

Otherwise, you may also try and give `override_function` a shot.

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you need to create your own sendmail style wrapper that is compatible with PHP.  When PHP calls `sendmail` to send mail, it opens a process, and writes the message data to sendmail which does whatever it does with the message.

You will need to reparse the message to send it, or perhaps just forward it as-is to your MTA after you log/account for the message.

Here is a sample script that supports no options but should get you started if you want to go this route:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

// you will likely need to handle additional arguments such as "-f"
$args = $_SERVER['argv'];

// open a read handle to php's standard input (where the message will be written to)
$fp = fopen('php://stdin', 'rb');

// open a temp file to write the contents of the message to for example purposes
$mail = fopen('/tmp/mailin.txt', 'w+b');

// while there is message data from PHP, write to our mail file
while (!feof($fp)) {
    fwrite($mail, fgets($fp, 4096));
}

// close handles
fclose($fp);
fclose($mail);

// return 0 to indicate acceptance of the message (not necessarily delivery)
return 0;
```

This script needs to be executable, so set its permissions to `755`.

Now, edit `php.ini` to point to this script (e.g. `sendmail_path = "/opt/php/php-sendmail.php -t -s"`)

Now in another script, try sendmail a message.

```
<?php

$ret = mail('drew@example.com', 'A test message', "<b>Hello User!</b><br /><br />This is a test email.<br /><br />Regards, The team.", "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nX-Mailer: MailerX", '-fme@example.com');

var_dump($ret);  // (bool)true
```

After calling that, the contents of `/tmp/mailin.txt` should contain something similar to the following:

```
To: drew@example.com
Subject: A test message
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:test3.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Mailer: MailerX

<b>Hello User!</b><br /><br />This is a test email.<br /><br />Regards, The team.
```

The contents of the above txt file are basically what you will either need to [parse](http://php.net/mailparse) so you can resend it, or you might be able to pass it directly to whatever MTA you use.  Note I did nothing with the arguments in this example, so don't forget about those.

Look at `man sendmail` for more documentation on that process.  [Here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/mail.c#202) is a link to the function in PHP that writes the mail to the `sendmail_path` directive in `php.ini`, it may help you understand what happens when you call `mail()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this example!

Answer (score 1):

I have used this for some time and I love it.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/